# PHP echo doesn't show up in webpage

Tags: php, html

So im fairly new in coding HTML CSS and PHP and now im focusing PHP.
Our professor asked us to incorporate PHP codes in our website (no database) and im trying to print a an array using a for loop and echo.

the problem is that the echo doesn't show in the webpage and I am now lost

below is my codes:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP Loops and Sorts</title>
<body>
<h1>PHP Loops and Sorts</h1>

<div class="container">
<?php
$dogs=Array("Labrador Retriever","German Shepherd","Bulldog","Golden Retriever","Poodle","Beagle","Rottweiler","Yorkshire Terrier","Siberian Husky","Dachshund","Chihuahua","Pug","Great Dane","Dobermann","Shih Tzu");
$cats=Array("Persian","Siamese","Maine Coon","Ragdoll","Sphynx","British Shorthair","Abyssinian","Bengal","Scottish Fold","Himalayan","Russian Blue","Siberian","Munchkin");
$birds=Array("Canaries","Budgies","Finches","Cockatiels","Quaker Parakeets","Pionus Parrots","Poicephalus Parrots","Amazon Parrots","Pyrrhura Conures","Peach-Faced Lovebirds");
$fishes=Array("Koi","Fantail","Oranda","Comet","Black Telescope","Butterfly Tail","Ryukin","Goldfish","Lionhead","Mirror Carp");

function countsize($array,$size){
    $size = count($array);
    return $size;
}

if(isset($_POST['btnShow']) )
    {
        $arraypick=$_POST['formAnimal'];
        $arrsize = countsize($arraypick,$size);
        for(&x = 0,$x<$arrsize,$x++){
            echo $arraypick[$x] . "<br>";
        }
    }
?>
Breeds of different kinds of animals. Select what animal's breed to be shown:<br>
    <select name="formAnimal">
  <option value="">Choose animal</option>
  <option value="dogs">Dog</option>
  <option value="cats">Cat</option>
  <option value="birds">Bird</option>
  <option value="fishes">Fish</option>
</select><br><br>
<div style="margin:auto,text-align:center;text-align:center">
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "btnShow" VALUE = "Show List">&emsp;
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "btnAsc" VALUE = "Show Ascending">&emsp;
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "btnDes" VALUE = "Show Descending">
</div>


<?php

echo $size

?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your syntax for the for loop is incorrect.
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: Please update your for loop as   for($x = 0;$x<$arrsize;$x++){ echo $arraypick[$x] . "<br>"; }. Also add `;` in line 47. ie echo $size;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(isset($_POST['btnShow']) )` are you sure it is set ?

From what we have in your code you can't even `POST`, you are missing your `form` tags

Try wrapping your inputs with :

```
<form method="POST">
    <!--inputs-->
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Ultimately, this was the piece of code i don't have thats why it cant run.

Comment: Awesome ! Glad I could help :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to close your head tag before your body tag.

You also don't need to pass in size to your method count size.

```
function countsize (&array) {
    return count(&array);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for the for loop is incorrect.  Check out the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

Also the `$size` variable is never declared in the scope you are using it.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't get how you're using $arrsize but you used &x instead of $x while initializing loop.

```
for($x = 0,$x<$arrsize,$x++){
  echo $arraypick[$x] . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change this lines of code:

```
$dogs=Array("Labrador Retriever","German Shepherd","Bulldog","Golden Retriever","Poodle","Beagle","Rottweiler","Yorkshire Terrier","Siberian Husky","Dachshund","Chihuahua","Pug","Great Dane","Dobermann","Shih Tzu");
$cats=Array("Persian","Siamese","Maine Coon","Ragdoll","Sphynx","British Shorthair","Abyssinian","Bengal","Scottish Fold","Himalayan","Russian Blue","Siberian","Munchkin");
$birds=Array("Canaries","Budgies","Finches","Cockatiels","Quaker Parakeets","Pionus Parrots","Poicephalus Parrots","Amazon Parrots","Pyrrhura Conures","Peach-Faced Lovebirds");
$fishes=Array("Koi","Fantail","Oranda","Comet","Black Telescope","Butterfly Tail","Ryukin","Goldfish","Lionhead","Mirror Carp");

function countsize($array,$size){
$size = count($array);
return $size;
```

}

```
$arraypick=$_POST['formAnimal'];
    $arrsize = countsize($arraypick,$size);
    for(&x = 0,$x<$arrsize,$x++){
        echo $arraypick[$x] . "<br>";
    }
```

To :

```
$animalArray['dogs']=Array("Labrador Retriever","German Shepherd","Bulldog","Golden Retriever","Poodle","Beagle","Rottweiler","Yorkshire Terrier","Siberian Husky","Dachshund","Chihuahua","Pug","Great Dane","Dobermann","Shih Tzu");
$animalArray['cats']=Array("Persian","Siamese","Maine Coon","Ragdoll","Sphynx","British Shorthair","Abyssinian","Bengal","Scottish Fold","Himalayan","Russian Blue","Siberian","Munchkin");
$animalArray['birds']=Array("Canaries","Budgies","Finches","Cockatiels","Quaker Parakeets","Pionus Parrots","Poicephalus Parrots","Amazon Parrots","Pyrrhura Conures","Peach-Faced Lovebirds");
$animalArray['fishes']=Array("Koi","Fantail","Oranda","Comet","Black Telescope","Butterfly Tail","Ryukin","Goldfish","Lionhead","Mirror Carp");

 function countsize($index){
  return count($animalArray[$index]);
}
    $arraypick=$_POST['formAnimal'];
    $arrsize = countsize($arraypick);
    for($x = 0;$x<$arrsize;$x++){
        echo $animalArray[$arraypick][$x] . "<br>";
    }
```

Comment: I think your goal here is to display the animals listed on each variable on the top. so ill edit it once more